# Node with GraphQL and React Require not defined

Tags: create-react-app, react-apollo, apollo-boost

I am developing a Node with GraphQL backend and just started working on the front end with `create-react-app`.

It was going well until I added this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';

import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4444/graphql'
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The Apollo code is what broke it to where it is telling me require is not defined. I understand the error to be concerning the utilization of require statements on the browser side which I am not.

Comment: Here's the [likely culprit](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1272). Based on [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4642) it's unclear whether this was finally addressed in CRA or not, but I see the `mjs` extension listed [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js). Maybe check and make sure you're using the latest version of CRA?

Comment: @DanielRearden, this is the version of CRA I have: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. Could it be I need to use an older version?

Comment: I changed the version of CRA, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting this error because I did not install all the preset packages I was supposed to install apparently.

I initially installed:

`npm install react-apollo apollo-boost jwt-decode`

When I should have installed:

`npm install react-apollo apollo-boost jwt-decode graphql-tag graphql --save`

Once I did so, the error went away. All I can say is that `graphql-tag` and `graphql` has some dependencies for `apollo-boost` and `react-apollo` I imagine.